# Application MFC desktop visual studio 2019 Certificat

Tags: c

I created an office app with visual studio 2019 with Cpp. It works well. When I copy it on my server (server 2019) with all the Dll and I launch Windows server blocks my application . windows defender says "unknown editor." Infact my app is not signed. If I bypass this alert off Microsoft defender my application works normally. I found on the internet utilities such as "signtool.exe". But how to have ".cert" or ".pfx" I think to get these certificates you have to pay, is that the case? Is it possible to generate these own certificates?
Thank you

Comment: Are you on a domain? There will be a root CA for your domain that can issue you a code signing certificate, and all machines on the domain will trust it.

Comment: You can generate your own certificates, yes, but they won't be trusted by the server unless they're signed by a trusted CA (your domain or an external one), or unless you manually install your signing certificate on the server as a trusted root. It's probably easiest to bypass the alert. Alternatively it's possible to clear the 'downloaded from the internet' flag on the app too, which probably stops Windows looking for a certificate.